# "Which php" showing incorrect path in mac os

Tags: php, xampp

I am doing "which php" in my mac book and its giving me the output as below :-
`/usr/bin/php`

While in path variable its showing me :-

```
~ manishk$  echo $PATH
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-5.6.24:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:
```

Which php should point to php-5.6.24 . 
Even php --version is giving me

```
PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I don't know where to set it to correct it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$PATH` variable is ment as a list of directories, where your command binaries can be found. So, you have to add the directory where the php binary is located.

For XAMPP this means, you'll have to add the following path to your `$PATH` variable:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin
```

As this is a symlink to `xamppfiles/bin`, you can also use this one:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```